# In pure CSS, is it possible to set margin equal to height of current element?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm have a vertical stack of items to which the user can append one by clicking a button, roughly like this.

```
<ol>
  <li><textarea></textarea></li>
  <li><textarea></textarea></li>
</ol>
<a data-action="additem">Add another</a>
```

I'm trying to write a CSS animation so that when the new `li` is inserted, the "Add another" smoothly slides down to its new resting place. Fixed height on the `li` tags is not an option, and I'm trying to avoid using the `max-height` animation hack because it can have weird layout effects.

I figured out that I could animate `margin-bottom` from *something* to 0 and have the desired effect, but I can't figure out how in CSS to express that I want the current height of the element to which this rule is applied. Percentages are measured relative to the *width* of the element, which isn't what I need here, and I can't think of a clever trick using `calc` or the like to express what I want to the browser.

Suggestions?

**EDIT**

I'm using a template with a repeat binding to add the items to the list. The JS only pushes another object into an observable array, and the framework handles the actual DOM insertion. The `li` tag has on it the following CSS to get it to enter smoothly:

```
animation: append forwards .5s;
```

And `append` is defined as:

```
@keyframes append {
    from {
        transform: translateX(10%);
        opacity: 0;
        margin-bottom: _____;
    }

    to {
        transform: none;
        opacity: 1;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you adding new items ?

Comment: Updated the question with an explanation. I don't have any JS outside the framework which acts on the DOM when the item is added.

Comment: you could use transform:scale(1,0) to transform:scale(0,1) ; and maybe a negative margin-bottom to positive 0 http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxfCd play with it

Comment: My primary goal is to get the `a` tag to move down smoothly: Transforms don't affect the bounding box, so even with the scale the "add more" still jumps. Using -1% on `margin-bottom` does a decent job faking it, but I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't have to be tuned based on the height of the content being inserted.

Comment: check it then, added a <a> and gave a min-height to li in regards of defaut textarea's height, told you :), play with it , scale + margin is an easy alternative to max-height :) else js to do the job if added lines have random's height

Comment: Sadly, that still doesn't solve the issue, since it requires coding the height of the element in ahead of time. The perf impact of running custom JS there is non-trivial, as it's not my code which actually appends the element to the list.

Comment: why don't use the max-height? what kind of issues are you talking about

Comment: Setting `max-height` large enough to make it effectively certain the CSS doesn't care about the element's height results in the `a` tag moving at 2000px/second, which basically looks like a jump. The goal is to move the height of the inserted element in the time specified in the `animation` property. There might be a way to mitigate that with an easing function, I suppose.

Comment: Can you show a demo then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Not currently...

I've come up against this frustrating issue a number of times, always trying to either animate a non-numeric value, access a specific property of the current element as an animation value, or animate an unspecified value to a specified one. Generally I always have to fall back to either some form of not-quite-perfect `max-height` animation (like you've already mentioned) or use a mixture of CSS and JavaScript/jQuery.

For your issue there are a few options, but none are exactly what you're after.

#### css only version (using duplicated markup and another animation)

- http://jsfiddle.net/7m8F9/2/
- http://jsfiddle.net/7m8F9/3/ <-- improved version using `bottom` and `position:relative`
- http://jsfiddle.net/7m8F9/5/ <-- even better version, going back to `translateY`

One trick often used with CSS-only hacks, is to duplicate markup — in this instance, the link iteself — and place it within parent wrappers that will be turned on or off by different means. The downsides to this method are that you get a rather ugly markup, and in this particular instance a bullet-number that appears jarringly (because of having to move the opacity animation from the `li` to the `textarea`).

The benefits of this method however are that by moving the link inside the `li` you can use `-100%` on the y-axis with a translate, or another offset method. Oddly though I can't work out what `translateY(-100%)` is calculating based upon... <del>it doesn't seem to be the parent height, perhaps it is the height of itself. For this reason I've updated the fiddle to use `bottom` and relative positioning instead, although in Firefox (on mac) this glitches briefly.</del>

It does seem to be that `translateY` is calculating percentage based on it's own height, so in order to get around this problem I've had to make use of position absolute and force the the link layer to assume the same dimensions as the `li`... annoying, as it involves z-indexing the `textarea` above the link, and an internal `span` to offset the link text, but at least it does work.

The following code works in the latest Firefox, and would work in other modern browsers if all the different browser-prefixes were correctly used to define the animation keyframes, I don't have time to set them all up right now however.

**markup:**

```
<ol class="list">
  <li><textarea></textarea><a class="add" href="#"><span>Add another</span></a></li>
  <li><textarea></textarea><a class="add" href="#"><span>Add another</span></a></li>
</ol>
```

**css:**

```
ol li {
  position: relative;
}
ol li .add {
  display: none;
}
ol li:last-child .add {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: slide;
}

ol li:last-child .add span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
}

.list li textarea {
  position: relative;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: append;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes append {
  from {
    transform: translateX(10%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: none;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

#### javascript version (code triggered translations)

http://jsfiddle.net/7m8F9/1/

The following obviously doesn't take into account the fact that you are using a template engine to power your DOM manipulations, but all the code needs to work properly is a before and after height of the list (to calculate the difference in height), and an event to trigger at the point where the new list item is added.

Sadly it is not yet possible to do this all in pure CSS, at least not as far as I have seen, perhaps once `calc` has leveled up...? Or perhaps if some way is introduced to reference the current elements dimensions, not just it's offset parent.

> *It should be noted I didn't have Internet Explorer around to test this with, but all other modern browsers seem happy.*

**markup:**

```
<ol class="list">
  <li><textarea></textarea></li>
  <li><textarea></textarea></li>
</ol>
<div class="add">
  <a href="#">Add another</a>
</div>
```

**javascript (with jQuery):**

```
function prefix(){
  for ( var a = ['Webkit','Moz','O','ms'], i=0, l = a.length; i<l; i++ ) {
    if ( document.body.style[a[i]+'AnimationName'] !== undefined ) {
      return { js: a[i], css: '-' + a[i].toLowerCase() + '-' };
    }
  }
  return { css:'', js:'' };
}

$(function(){
  $('.add a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var pref = prefix(),
      link = $(this).parent(), 
      list = $('.list'),
      lihi = list.height(),
      liad = $('<li><textarea></textarea></li>').appendTo(list),
      lihd = lihi - list.height();
      link.css(pref.css + 'transform', 'translateY(' + lihd + 'px)');
    setTimeout(function(){link.addClass('translate-zero transition-all');},0);
    setTimeout(function(){
      link.css(pref.css + 'transform', '');
      link.removeClass('translate-zero transition-all');
    },500);
  });
});
```

**css:**

```
.transition-all {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.translate-zero {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0) !important;
  -moz-transform: translateY(0) !important;
  -ms-transform: translateY(0) !important;
  -o-transform: translateY(0) !important;
  transform: translateY(0) !important;
}

.list li {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: append;
}

@keyframes append {
  from {
    transform: translateX(10%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: none;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

#### redesign version

A number of times I have hit a similar issue, only to find a redesign helps do away with the problem and can often actually improve usability. In your case it may be best to place the "add link" above the list (or top right), or integrate the button as a floating icon somewhere... where-ever you put it, it is best to try and keep it in a static location, moving interaction points can be annoying for users, especially if they wish to add more than one item in quick succession.

[image: example of top right link]

Comment: A question I was already thinking about was how to animate an element between contexts in the DOM; the idea would have been similar to how IE and Chrome keep the tab close button under the mouse until you move away. I suspect that too is impossible.

Answer (score -2):

The simplest solution that i could think of is this.

When you add a new li element, just append it in the dom.

```
liMarkup = '<li><textarea></textarea></li>'
$('ol').append(liMarkup);
$('ol').find('li').last().css('display','none');
$('ol').find('li').last().show('fast');
```

This would work as per your requirement :) I hope it helps.

Working [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jazz_sylvia/3QW9X/3/)

EDIT: Its easy and better to do it in JS.

Comment: Your edit is unsubstantiated. First of all this is not JS, it's `jQuery` (not everyone will/can use `jQuery`), second why is it better?